# Codepush an update to two different react native android apps?

Tags: react-native, code-push

Is it possible to codepush an update to two android apps. Those two apps are using same codebase but different app name and bundle id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible, as long as you are not using different assets(not native assets). I am talking about those who are loaded from javascript bundle.

`Codepush` doesn't really care about your app name or bundle id, it is only responsible to  upload your bundled `js` code.